# How Do I add a local Mysql user for Rails Dev?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a problem where I always need to give simple access to my local account, and don't want to deal with typing in my root password a million times on my local machine. How do I give perms so i can type 'mysql' with my local user and get access to everything?

Comment: This appears to be a note/tutorial rather than a question. While it's usually fine to post things like that on here please consider rephrasing it into a question and then post the answer.

Comment: Do you mean to the title? Or the body?

Comment: Post the question as the first post and then reply to it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the local user to the dev machine perms to select from databases, and a local_rails_user account (feel free to sub your own) permissions to run any migrations. Just thought i'd store it here in case anyone else wants to use it. NOT FOR PRODUCTION MACHINES.

Local Rails User:

```
insert into user(host,user,password) values ('localhost','local_rails_user','');
grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD on *.* to
   'local_rails_user'@'localhost';
```

Local Viewer:

```
insert into user(host,user,password) values ('localhost','','');
grant SELECT on *.* to ''@'localhost';
```

Make sure to "flush privileges" after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use root?  This is your local machine, after all.

There is such a thing as being too paranoid.